# Calculate voltage(sensor weight) to Kg

Tags: voltage, sensor, power-electronics

I want to get weight for load vehicle in Kg,
I Used this [product](https://mechatronics.by/en/products/load-control/eurosens-dps-axle-load-sensor/#prettyPhoto)  and I received like this output '1.361'
How I can calculate(convert) this value to Kg(Kilogram)

Comment: Where’s the engineering involved? You need product support.

Comment: Hey! I think it's something to calculate? I mean maybe it's there formula to calculate? 
because output value is Voltage

Comment: you have to use known weights to calibrate the sensor

Comment: @jsotola you are right! but this tool just output this value type!! how I can convert it!

Comment: @GeeSuth you know what *calibration* means, right? You use a known input to your system (here: weights) and observe the output for that known input. Then you make a conversion table/function. That's how you can convert it. It's that simple.

Comment: Try reading the datasheets and other supplied documents, they are supposed to cover these type of questions. If they wouldn't, how would anyone use the product?

Comment: '1.361' you get from where? Is this voltage, text string over communication, or what?